# ActiveReports 2.0 Designer trouble

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting, activereports

I have a project where I use ActiveReports 2.0. So when I need to edit my report with the designer view, it just don't happen and all I can see is the .rpx file. 
I need to draw new columns and add new data to those old reports, but I can't open them with the designer... how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are working with ActiveReports 2.0 for .NET and not ActiveReports 2.0 for VB6. The RPX file is the report layout which can be directly opened inside visual studio. Do you get any error message when trying to open the RPX file?

You may provide the RPX file over the ActiveReports support forum using this [link](http://help.gcactivereports.com/groups/forum/reporting/activereports-8/).

Comment: Obsolete versions of Active Reports. Not compatible with VS2008 :\
Solution: VS2005!